# IPhone 13 does not ring thru speaker with bluetooth connected

Tags: iphone, headphones, speakers

I have an IPhone 13 When I am at work I am allowed to wear ear buds, but my phone does not ring thru speaker when the ear buds are connected.  When i take them out for something i am not hearing my phone ring and i am missing important work calls please help.

Comment: When you take them out, put them in your case so they disconnect automatically re-enabling your iPhone speaker so you can hear the ring.

Comment: Thank you but my problem is i dont always have the case on me because i am at work and leave it on my desk when i walk away to do something

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in iOS and I've already reported it like 4 months ago. apple doesn't seem to be in a real hurry to fix it either. also there is a similar bug where ringtones don't play through bluetooth speakers but all other sounds will.